# use erased element in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I'm wondering if I can still access/modify the data of an erased element in a map inside a function like the following:

```
struct CustStruct {
  int a;
  int b;
};

void useAfterErase() {
  map<int, CustStruct> myMap;
  myMap[0] = {0,1};
  myMap[3] = {2,3};
  myMap[4] = {4,5};

  auto itr = myMap.find(3);
  auto & element = itr->second;

  myMap.erase(itr);

  // access after erased
  element.a = 100;
  element.b = 100;

  cout << element.a << " " << element.b << endl;
}
```

assume that it is single thread and the access/modify is right after the deletion before the map is modified then is the access/modify always safe?

Comment: nope, not with a ref. undefined behavior. make a copy first

Comment: You have a dangling reference, it is not safe.

Comment: `right after the deletion before the map is modified` - deleting an element is modifying the map.

Comment: Trying to access any deleted thing is UB.

Comment: Remember that it may appear to work *for you*. It doesn't mean it will always work. That's the nature of undefined behavior, it can produce any behavior, including the one you might expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's never safe. The object will almost certainly be destroyed when it's removed from the map. (If not, when would it be?)